# Tomcat Server returns error 404 ... And no, I don't use web.xml, .jsp or .html files

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, tomcat

I've deployed my spring-boot server to AWS for the first time and for some reason it doesn't work. I did everything as in the guide but it returns "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.", although when I run it at my localhost, it works properly. Does anybody know what could be causing it? (I think maybe I somehow incorrectly generate war file or sth)(please tell if you need any code examples)
Order of my actions:
0. Created AWS account.
1. Configured building of WAR files(firstly created war-exploded configuration, then simply war configuration, attached to war-exploded, because in other case I'd have to create empty war config and set it up by myself)
2. Created Elastic Beanstalk web-server environment with newest Tomcat platform and uploaded war file.
3. Waited... and tried to open auto-generated URL.
And then I saw 404 Tomcat error.
I tried to generate different war files(and once jar), upload them, created a few new environments, but nothing changed((
Code of main class:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
public class HeysmellApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HeysmellApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And controller(I have another one, this is just to handle base request in order to check whether server works or not, but it works on my localhost):

```java
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RequestMapping("/")
@RestController
public class MainController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getMain(){
        return "Hello, it's my API";
}
    @GetMapping("/help")
    public String getHelp() {
        return "not implemented, sorry";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the following [mcve]: Deployment steps, sample code, testing method

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I added info about how I've deployed my app. Do you need any more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. The main problem was that Elastic Beanstalk need port 5000 to work properly, after I changed it my server started to handle requests. But, it only works with jar files and when I try to deploy war file the problem remains the same. In any case, it works and that's enough for me.